# Google Chrome hotkey "Ctrl+W" has changed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, hotkeys, google-search

I have no idea how it got changed, but now when press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in Google Chrome it works as a hot key for "Scroll Up". And I want it back, so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> would close a tab.

I have not found a way to re-bind my hotkeys in Google Chrome.

Comment: If you are in windows, CTRL-F4 closes tabs.. since like '95.  In everything including chrome, firefox, edge, etc.  I know this doesn't answer you question but you might as well get used to it.

Comment: Try Settings, Reset and Cleanup and restore settings to Default.

Comment: Does this happen in Incognito mode?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas yeah, but its so much easire to press ctrl+w then ctrl+f4.

Comment: @John thought about it too, thank, but this would also delete some more stuff which i have really no intention to delete.

Comment: @harrymc yes, it does

Comment: btw i just found out that Ctrl+R does not work as well

Comment: This should be closed/deleted as the premise of the question is incorrect and appears to be down to an application conflict.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is self-solved in an idiosyncratic way that’s not really useful to others.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The answer is: you should close your WC3Champions Launcher.

Comment: Can you explain how this resolved the problem? It sounds as though your question's premise was incorrect, and the problem wasn't about Chrome at all.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the accepted answer (using the tick icon) in order to remove the question from the unanswered/unresolved list: As this was the actual issue, and; Seeing as this answer has a number of negative votes, others may still attempt to (needlessly) suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably swapped your WASD keys for arrow keys accidentally.

Check out this link for more:  https://appuals.com/fix-wasd-and-arrow-keys-are-switched/

Comment: That's a new keyboard and getting know with it takes time, I had the same problem with modern keyboards. And didn't knew for 2 minutes what to do.